# GoogleAppEngine access app.yaml contents inside the app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a python GAE app. Inside my `webapp2` code I would like to access some of the properties defined in the `app.yaml`.

I know it's possible to export environment variables and access them inside my python app using `os.environ`, but is there a way to directly access `app.yaml` contents without exporting environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
import yaml
with open('app.yaml') as fd:
    data = yaml.load(fd)
    logging.error('data=%s' % data)
```

Comment: Thank you. This will be my fallback if I don't find another way to get it from the GAEapi. I'll wait before I accept the answer.